# Trying to add a foreign key in SQLPLUS command line

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE sales_rep
(
    slsrep_number VARCHAR (20),
    first VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    last VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT slsrep_number_pk PRIMARY KEY (slsrep_number)
);

CREATE TABLE customer
(
    customer_number VARCHAR (20),
    CONSTRAINT customer_number_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_number)
);

ALTER TABLE customer
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_slsrep_number FOREIGN KEY (slsrep_number)
        REFERENCES sales_rep(slsrep_number);
```

> ERROR AT LINE 3 ORA-00904: "SLSREP_NUMBER": INVALID IDENTIFIER

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your customer table doesn't have a column called slsrep_number. The first column mentioned in the foreign key definition belongs to the table you're creating the foreign key on. eg. `ADD CONSTRAINT fk_slsrep_number FOREIGN KEY (slsrep_number)` should probably be `ADD CONSTRAINT fk_slsrep_number FOREIGN KEY (customer_number)`

Answer (score 1):

You have no column called `slsrep_number` in the `customer` table.  Just do:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    customer_number VARCHAR(20),
    slsrep_number VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_customer_number PRIMARY KEY (customer_number),
    CONSTRAINT fk_slsrep_number FOREIGN KEY (slsrep_number) REFERENCES sales_rep(slsrep_number)
);
```

You can use a separate `alter table`, but you might as well put it into the table definition.

Comment: Won't that still fail? Shouldn't it be `CONSTRAINT fk_slsrep_number FOREIGN KEY (customer_number) REFERENCES sales_rep(slsrep_number)`?

Comment: @Boneist . . . That would be another interpretation of the right answer to the question.  I am guessing that the two tables have different primary keys, but your interpretation is quite possible.  (Note:  I added in the `slsrep_number` column into the table.)

Comment: Aah, I missed the additional column. Duh!